# Removing Duplicated Values Based on Lastupdated Date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am trying to remove duplicated cases on our database.
There are 3 fields: `ProjectID`,`ClientID`,`LastVerified`.

We had an issue with one of our apps and it has created multiple new `ProjectID`.

What i want to do is remove the duplicates and only leave the row that was last Verified.
For instance:

```
    ProjectID   ClientID    LastVerified
     20773        336106    2016-07-29 01:38:37.450
     20869        336106    2016-08-23 11:19:51.153
```

Here i would like to keep the second row as it was last verified.

I am using SQL database 
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Tag RDBMS which you are using

Comment: Is ProjectID relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DELETE X FROM
(
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY LastVerified DESC) R
     FROM @t
) X
WHERE R!=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete a row if there exists another row with same ClientID that is newer:

```
delete from tablename t1
where exists (select * from tablename t2
              where t2.ClientID = t1.ClientID
                and t2.LastVerified > t1.LastVerified)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps u, and max(projectid) helps to find the last verified.
so the query become simple

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE PROJECTID NOT IN 
(SELECT MAX(PROJECTID) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY CLIENTID)
```